# Why is this integer power of 2 code faster?

Tags: c++, performance, c++14, compiler-optimization, clang++

So, I am doing a lot of calculations which involve calculating powers of 2, so I decided to write the fastest possible function to compute them. I originally wrote the following:

```
inline
auto pow2(const int exp){
  auto base = 1;
  return base<<=exp;
}
```

This is blazing fast because of the exact bit shifting in one pass, but then I decided to test the following:

```
inline
auto pow2(const int exp, unsigned int base=1){
  return base<<=exp;
}
```

The function is the invoked as:

```
result = pow2(exponent);
```

This made my code 30% faster (clang++ and g++ with -O3), but I am not sure why. I suspect that it is because the compiler somehow avoids allocating the `base` variable and only uses a temporary object, but it's just wild guessing; I don't understand exactly what instructions are avoided because of this syntax. Any ideas?

**Edit:** The assembler output is as follows:

First version (`base` var in the body of the function):

```
pow2(int):
        mov     ecx, edi
        mov     eax, 1
        sal     eax, cl
        ret
```

Second version (`base` var in the declaration):

```
pow2(int, unsigned int):
        mov     eax, esi
        mov     ecx, edi
        sal     eax, cl
        ret
```

**Edit2:** Some more information: from the feedback in the comments I decided to test the code on a different machine and got something interesting. On my work computer with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz, this code is indeed 30% faster. On my laptop, with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz the two versions benchmark the same.

Comment: what does assembly output say?

Comment: [Go to this link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) and enter your code there.

Comment: You don't need the `=`, just `return base << exp`.

Comment: `unsigned` vs `int`... and overflow handling.

Comment: The only read difference is that in the second case base is `unsigned int`.

Comment: Without seeing your testing code, it's impossible to determine what's causing the difference. (The `unsigned` thing is, I think, a red herring.)

Comment: @Jarod42 There's no particular reason I can think of why a compiler would need to do anything different when left-shifting a known-positive value in a signed context.

Comment: Wild guess: the `1` in `base` (i.e. in `esi`) stayed there longer (as in: the corresponding `mov esi,1` done by the caller started being processed in the pipeline earlier), so when `sal` is reached the data dependency is already satisfied (it does not need to wait for the previous `mov eax, 1` to complete); the `mov eax,esi` should effectively disappear on recent CPUs that support move elimination.

Comment: Still, it is crucial to see the test code and how it gets compiled - these functions are most probably being inlined in your test function, so it's possible that you are looking at the disassembly of the generated non-inline functions, which however are not the ones being actually tested.

Comment: The second example is missing mov esi,1. Reordering doesn't help because there is a dependency on both the exponent and the base value for `sal eax,cl` . The `mov eax,1` could be first, but then the `mov ecx,edi` will cause the `sal eax,cl` to wait for ecx to be updated.

Comment: @rcgldr: IIRC register-register moves should disappear on recent processors due to move elimination - the register renaming is effective immediately, so the data dependency is against the content of `edi`, not against the `mov ecx,edi`.

Comment: With -O3 on an inlined function it will be hard to determine anything from the assembly code without its context. For example in the second case, the second instruction is not affecting your pow calculation. Its likely mangled with another instruction where this function is called, since it is declared as inline.
The `mov     ecx, edi` will however be beneficial for the processor when pipelining instructions since the 3rd line is dependent on the first (eax)

Comment: @MatteoItalia - thanks for pointing that out. I'm not sure when register to register move elimination first occurred. For Intel X86,  Ivy Bridge, Haskell, ... ?

Comment: @rcgldr: from what I read around, it seems like it should be present at least since Ivy Bridge.

Comment: @Matteo Italia This is interesting, I run the code on a different machine and the two versions have no difference in performance. Maybe it's because of the register move elimination?

Comment: What are the processors of the two machines? Can you provide the test code and its assembly?

Comment: Why not `return 1 << exp`?